# ResourceManager will not start, bad scheduler setting

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

Recently YARN and more specifically Resource Manager will not start. Hunting through the logs in /var/log/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-scottvih2sa-92-namenode.log I found the error:

> 2015-12-02 20:18:13,287 FATAL resourcemanager.ResourceManager (ResourceManager.java:main(1241)) - Error starting ResourceManager
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal capacity of -1.0 for node-label=default in queue=root, valid capacity should in range of [0, 100].

I look at the property: `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.default.capacity` with Ambari and indeed it is set to `-1`. I change this property along with the maximum-capacity property and YARN/Resource Manager will start.

So I know what is the problem but don't know why. I've been using Ambari blueprints to install HDP 2.2.x for many months and up until recently everything has been fine with YARN. I'm not overriding any of the scheduler properties with the blueprint so I don't think I'm doing anything wrong.

Is anyone else seeing the same thing? Could it be something I'm doing wrong in my blueprint if others are not having a problem? If this an HDP/Ambari bug in the latest release?

My version is HDP 2.2.9.0-3393

Comment: I am using HDP 2.3.0. I never faced this problem. The capacity for the default queue is always set to 95:   <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity</name>
    <value>95</value>
    <description>Default queue target capacity.</description>
  </property>

Comment: I think this is a new problem with 2.2.9. Good to know 2.3.0 doesn't have the problem.

Comment: I believe I'm having the same issue: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6519/resourcemanager-cannot-start.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the thread slm stated https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6519/resourcemanager-cannot-start.html it was implying that Ambari might have something to do with the problem. I looked and I was using Ambari 2.1.0. I changed to use Ambari 2.1.2 and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and it turned out to be an due to 2 options that were getting applied with a value that was out of bounds for both of them.

/etc/hadoop/conf/capacity-scheduler.xml

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.default.capacity</name>
  <value>-1</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.default.maximum-capacity</name>
  <value>-1</value>
</property>
```

To work around the issue I removed these entries and restarted ResourceManager service.

**NOTE:** I had to make these changes through Ambari, though, editing the above file did not seem to take, not sure why.

[image: ss1]

[image: ss2]

The above looks to be a bug in Ambari: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-13232. Thanks to JonasStraub for helping to dig this all up.

#### References

- [ResourceManager cannot start](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6519/resourcemanager-cannot-start.html)

Comment: Yes I believe this is the same problem. I found that I could set these settings to 100 (like they are set in HDP 2.3) and Resource Manager will start. Problem with this is I'm using Ambari along with blueprints so the whole process is automated to deploy Hadoop. I don't want to code up a workaround for this, I'd rather have this issue fixed in Ambari/HDP.

Comment: @scottfrolich - same here, I'm using blueprints to auto install, don't want to muck w/ this either.